# Unable to reducers in combined reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to add authenticationReducer to combined reducer, but it is giving me the following error,

[image]

[image]
index.ts,

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { authenticationReducer } from "./authentication-reducer";
import { AuthResponse } from "../../services/authentication-service";

export interface StoreState {
  authentication: AuthResponse;
}

export const rootReducer = combineReducers<StoreState>({
  authentication: authenticationReducer
});
```

Action,

```
import {
  authenticationService,
  AuthResponse
} from "../../services/authentication-service";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { AuthActionTypes } from "./types";

export interface AuthenticationAction {
  type: AuthActionTypes;
  payload: AuthResponse | null;
}

export const authenticate = (credentials: any) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch<AuthenticationAction>({
      type: AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATING,
      payload: null
    });

    await authenticationService
      .authenticate(credentials)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.access_token) {
          console.log(response);
          localStorage.setItem("authResponse", JSON.stringify(response));

          dispatch<AuthenticationAction>({
            type: AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATED,
            payload: response.data
          });
        } else {
          dispatch<AuthenticationAction>({
            type: AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED,
            payload: null
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        dispatch({
          type: AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED,
          payload: error
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Reducer,

```
import { AuthActionTypes } from "../actions/types";
import { AuthenticationAction } from "../actions/authentication-actions";
import { AuthResponse } from "../../services/authentication-service";

let authResponse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authResponse") || "{}");
const initialState = authResponse
  ? { loggedIn: true, authResponse: authResponse }
  : {};

export const authenticationReducer = (
  state: AuthResponse,
  action: AuthenticationAction
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATED:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Store Config,

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
};
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets try to assign `default value` of state in `reducer` to `initialState`. Initially it might be empty/undefined that's why you are getting error "`undefined` is not assignable to `AuthResponse`"

```
export const authenticationReducer = (
  state: AuthResponse = initialState, // assigning default value
  action: AuthenticationAction
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.AUTHENTICATED:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Another hack is, you can change `state` type to `any`. but that will not check your defined type.